# Can't obtain Document set author via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I try to print Authors of all items of docset list in powershell script:

```
Clear-Host

$web = Get-SPWeb "http://dogovor.ab.ru"
$list = $web.Lists["Agreements"]

$AllItems = $list.Items
foreach ($t in $AllItems)
{
    if ($t.ContentType.Name -eq "Agreement")
    {
        $t.Properties["Author"] # <- null

        $t
    }
}
```

but the property "Created By" (internal name "Author") is always null, while I can see it on form. 

May be there are a list of properties to retrieve or something else..
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using hard code the name its better to use.

> [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Author

Your code could look something like this

```
$url = "<url>"
$list = "<list title>"
$ctName = "<name contenttype>"
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists[$list]

$list.Items | % {
   $item = $_
   if ($item.ContentType.Name -eq $ctName)
   {
       $item[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Author]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for refactoring, but this not helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `$t["Author"]` instead of `$t.Properties["Author"]`

Comment: tried, same result